# Convert multiple FirebaseObjectObservable into a FirebaseListObservable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The snippet is part of a bigger code. Generally I have an object on firebase database called users (it's not a list). I need to get some of them and then convert into `Array` or `FirebaseListObservable`.

```
Observable.merge(...[
  this.db.object('users/user1'),
  this.db.object('users/user2'),
  this.db.object('users/user3'),
  this.db.object('users/user4'),
  this.db.object('users/user5')
]).subscribe(user => {
  console.log(user);
});
```

This return me user by user, however I need to get all users together. I need to do it in sync. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and this is how I'm solving it for the moment:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    let observables = [];
    for (let user of users) {
        observables.push(this.db.object(user))
    }       
    return Observable.combineLatest(...observables, (...results) => { return results });
}
```

What I did not manage to do is to return it as FirebaseListObservable.

Comment: That is a feasible solution. I have found other that works for me better. I query firebase with list method and specify a value of key that I want to have.